# Awk same string in a specified column

Tags: bash, scripting, awk

I have data structured generally like this:

```
name letter surname
```

This is a real world example:

```
Jake A Lincoln
Phil B Baker
Paul B Howard
John B Baker
...
```

I want to use awk to check for the same string in the surname column. This is what I came up with:

```
awk 'NF==3{sur=$3;next} NF==3{newsur=$3;next} if ($sur == $newsur){ print $1,$2,$3 }'
```

But I really didn't think it would work.

Comment: Whats your expected output?

Comment: if there are two identical surnames, I want to print both full names like this: `Phil B Baker : John B Baker`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ awk '$3 in a{print a[$3]":"$0;next}{a[$3]=$0}' file
Phil B Baker:John B Baker
```

If you have many such names in different order, it would be best to store them in array and print it in the end.

```
awk '($3 in t){ln[$3]=t[$3]":"$0;next}{t[$3]=$0}END{for(s in ln) print ln[s]}' file
```

To store just names and print the last name once, do:

```
$ awk '$3 in t{ln[$3]=t[$3]":"$1;next}{t[$3]=$1}END{for(s in ln) print ln[s],"("s")"}' file
Phil:John (Baker)
```

Comment: One last thing, if I didn't want to print the whole name (all three columns), but just the names and the surname at the end like this: `Phil : John (Baker)` would that be possible?

Comment: unreal, thank you so much! i'm learning so much from you guys :)